# Delete all folders older than X days using Shell

Tags: linux, shell, cron

my backups are stored in folders. e.g

```
 **05092013** > 
 - File1.sql
 - File2.sql
 - File1.tar
 - File2.tar
```

and so on.

**Now I want to delete all Folders that are older than X Days.**

I tried this

```
find $FILEDIR -mtime +14 -exec rm {} \;
```

but it only deletes all files and not the folders. how can i delete all files and folders that are older?

can someone help me?

Thx in advance cSGermany

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `-r`?

`find "$FILEDIR" -mtime +14 -exec rm -ir {} \;`

Change `-ir` to just `-r` if you know what you're doing.

Or use `-delete`:

```
find "$FILEDIR" -mtime +14 -delete
```

But please, please make sure you know what you're doing.

You could add checks like this too to make sure $FILEDIR is always somewhere in your home directory:

```
[[ $FILEDIR == /home/abc/* ]] && find "$FILEDIR" -mtime +14 -delete
```

Comment: I don't know exactly what I'm doing ;) This is quite new to me. But it is not possible to delete files which are not in the FILEDIR directory?!

Comment: so: find $FILEDIR -type d -mtime +14 -exec rm -r {} \; should work?

Comment: @cSGermany Add `-mindepth 1`: `[[ $FILEDIR == /home/abc/* ]] && find "$FILEDIR" -mindepth 1 -mtime +14 -delete`. Another option to add checks without using `[[ ]]` is to use `-wholename`: `find "$FILEDIR" -mindepth 1 -wholename '/home/abc/*' -mtime +14 -delete`.

Answer (score 1):

- to find **only** directory, you could add `find $FILEDIR -type d ...` it could avoid to remove files (e.g. files under your given root dir) by mistake.
- to remove a non-empty directory,  you need `rm -r`, so `-r` option is important here.

Comment: it works but also deletes the mainfolder "backups". how can i prevent it to delete this folder?

Comment: it seems konsolebox's answer had solved your problem? @cSGermany

Comment: Booth answers solved it! Thank you for that. But the Problem is that it also deletes the main folder.

Comment: You'r right. I'm not used to get answers that fast, like from you two guys, so i overlooked it :D